# Symfony Ratchet отправка сообщения от сервера

Tags: websocket, symfony3, ratchet

В проекте используется бандл Ratchet для Symfony 3. Никак не могу найти как инициировать ивент на стороне сервера для отправки сообщения. Например, при обновлении БД нужно оповестить всех клиентов, но сделать это должен сервер.

P.S. [Использую вот это](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: укажите какой именно бандл вы используете?

Comment: вы используете Ratchet это понятно, а что за бандл вы используете?

Comment: Немного не понимаю Вашего вопроса. Я, видимо, не правильно написал. Используется не бандл, а просто класс.